# Conditionally modifying multiple strings with For

Tags: visual-foxpro

So I have 13 binary values, which I call b_1... b_13, and based off these values I'd like to either set something I call indic_j to a previously defined string called inf_j, or nothing at all. Is it possible to do this without using 13 "If..." statements? What I have tried is below:

```
inf_1 = "aaaaa"
inf_2 = "bbbbb"
```

... and so on defining 13 infs, where aaaaa, bbbbb etc are names of columns in a table that I want to select.

```
FOR j = 1 to 13

IF b_j = 1 THEN "indic_"+j = inf_j + ",";
ELSE "indic_"+j = ""
ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

Also, before this I haven't introduced anything called indic_1, indic_2, etc. Is this needed?

My end goal is to transfer selected columns over to Excel. I've no problems doing this with predetermined columns, but I'm not sure how to allow for selected columns only.

I've tried using 13 IF statements, but I'm getting operator/operand type mismatch errors. My code currently is

```
IIF(b_1 = 1, indic_1 = inf_1 + ",",indic_1 = "")
IIF(b_2 = 1, indic_1 = inf_2 + ",",indic_1 = "")
IIF(b_3 = 1, indic_1 = inf_3 + ",",indic_1 = "")
```

and so on for 13 times, and then

```
SELECTIONRANG = indic_1 + indic_2 + indic_3 + indic_4 + indic_5 + indic_6 +indic_7 + indic_8 + indic_9 + indic_10 + indic_11 + indic_12 + indic_13
SELECTIONRANGE = LEFT(SELECTIONRANG,LEN(Selectionrang)-1)
```

Comment: The pseudo code you posted would not work in FoxPro. Looks as if you perhaps want to use arrays or collections instead of 13 individual "b_" and "inf_" variables, and perhaps `Do Case / EndCase` rather than 13 `IF` blocks

Comment: You're welcome. I'd guess you'd get more detailed replies if you'd post more concrete details, like the actual "b" values / types and what you want to do with the "indic" result

Comment: Oh right. the b values are binary, either 1 or 0.  Essentially, what i want to do is pull out certain columns from a data sheet depending on whether the corresponding b_# value is 1 or 0. If it's 1, i'd like to include it, and if 0 i don't wanna include it. 

E.g. if the name of one column is aaaa and another is bbbb, if b_1 is 1, i'd like indic_1 to become aaaa, and if its 0, then indic_1 would be "", then i'd add all the indics together and use string to select which columns i wanted.

Comment: If the data is more or less like "tables", many people would use "cursors" in FoxPro for temporary import / export tasks, see also the `Create Cursor` command. And you'll probably find lots of useful samples via web search on keywords like "vfp excel import", including COM automation and ODBC / OleDB approaches alternatively to the old `Append From` command

Comment: Hey Stefan, thanks again. I'm not familiar with cursors but i'll look into it. The data's in .dbf files, and at the end i'd like to export to an excel sheet. Dyou know of a good resource I could use?

Comment: The `Copy To ... Type XL5` command is the classical counterpart of `Append From ...` in VFP to get started. If you'd need to go beyond it's capabilities, there are Cetin Basoz' "Vfp2Excel" examples, and Tamar Granor's articles to name two very knowledgeable authors among many others you'll find via web search

Comment: Sorry late in the comments.  The values/indicators you are referring to.  Are they actually COLUMNS of a given table you are trying to work with vs just variables?  Showing more actual samples, even if mach-up to show start and final values REGARDLESS of the method... cursor or otherwise.  Please edit your question and add some additional for clarification.

Comment: Hi DRapp, thanks. the aaaa, bbbb... and so on are names of columns of a given table. i'm trying to select them all. i've edited the question to better reflect this!

Answer (score 0):

You could create te variable name as a string and use it with &
As:

```
ind = 13
Var = "inf_" + ind
&Var ** inf_13
```